Should apologetics take into account deeper convictions behind rational arguments?
Lately I came across What are Christian responses to the atheistic argument that God is an unnecessary and overly complicated extra step? and posted an answer to it. Although I wrote my post in response to the question, it was a bit out of place as it didn't exactly answer the question. So I rewrote things (quite) a bit and now post my own question.
I think we can say that nowadays the main challenge for apologetics is justifying faith in the face of atheism. In fact, there are two challenges. One is justifying faith for ourselves. The other is justifying faith for others.
The goal of justifying faith for ourselves is to protect our own faith. We can't avoid being confronted with arguments against God's existence. But we want to keep our faith plausible. So for each of those arguments, we must find a satisfying counterargument. Finding satisfying counterarguments may be hard, but we only need to satisfy our own intellect.
The goal of justifying faith for others is to help them overcome their objections and accept faith. Then it often won't do to just take certain arguments against God's existence and counter those. One must engage in dialogue, listen carefully, try sincerely to understand their objections, and try to see where those objections come from, what's behind them, and what's driving them. Only then one can address their objections in a helpful way.
Allow me to explain. I think many atheists would claim their view is based on objective facts and rational arguments. Now facts in themselves may be objective, but how we search for them and how we filter, interpret, and explain them is very subjective, as that depends on certain deeper convictions in ourselves. In the same way, our rational arguments also depend on our deeper convictions. This counts for atheists and believers alike.
We all live with such deeper convictions. They feel so familiar though that we're hardly aware of them until perhaps confronted with incompatible convictions. We have many deeper convictions based on character, culture, upbringing, experiences, or whatever. These convictions also determine how we look at God. For some people, a deeper conviction might be a strong longing for autonomy. They would be less inclined to submit to some god dictating to them what (not) to do. Other people may long for security. They would be more inclined to hope for some god protecting them.
With that in mind, I'd not be surprised if large parts of atheism are rooted in (perhaps valid) resentment against church and religion and religious upbringing. Some atheist arguments could just be rational expressions of the underlying resentment. Or perhaps more precisely, some atheist arguments may serve to rationally dissociate oneself from the underlying resentment. The strongest way to dissociate oneself from resentment against religion is by denying God himself.
Now if we'd only bothered countering rational atheist arguments, then we'd satisfied our own intellects but failed to see what's behind those arguments. Once we see the deeper convictions driving atheism, however, it becomes clear that it doesn't help so much to carry a debate by scientific or philosophical arguments, unless you first check your own deeper convictions as well as the convictions of your atheist opponents.
So here's the question: should apologetics focus on rational arguments only, or should it take into account deeper convictions behind rational arguments as well?
After @SuperFlash's answer down below, I realized I need to make my question more specific. My question is not whether apologetics should find a rational argument for or against any possible personal conviction or experience or feeling. It's more whether apologetics should take into account the role of deeper convictions in general. So let's make my question more specific:

Should apologetics acknowledge the plain possibility that there might be deeper convictions driving rational arguments? Regardless of what specific convictions may look like?
If so, should apologetics also incorporate reasoning how deeper convictions in general may drive rational arguments about God? Or perhaps more accurate how rational arguments may serve to justify deeper convictions with relation to God?
And again if so, should apologetics also identify certain universal deeper convictions? Like longing for autonomy or security?


You can't really assign deeper convictions/predispositions to somebody else when it's so difficult to even pinpoint one's own deeper convictions/predispositions.  I think what you're describing is the difference between apologetic debate and conversation.

I don't have time to Answer now, but a lot of apologists I follow argue that mere logic can't bring one to God, because rejection of God is ultimately based on spiritual factors. Which is to say, the answer isn't only "it should", but "it must".

I do not understand the obsession with arguing with atheists. The fool hath said in his heart, God is not' saith the Psalmist. Best not argue with a fool or one becomes like them.

@NigelJ I see it as "engagement" not obsession.  Engagement implies willingness to listen and to see the world from someone's eyes until the atheist can say to you: "you can now see my difficulties", at which point you score one point toward leading the (hopefully not hardened) atheist to reciprocate and see the world from your own eyes, which is the eyes of faith.  I do this with someone and was successful.  Have you done much listening to their difficulties?  Try it, and be compassionate; it can change you for the better. True faith is not afraid, darkness cannot overcome it (John 1:5).

@GratefulDisciple I do not see things with the eyes of others. I see what is given me to see. I do not sympathise with that which rejects Deity. Paul the apostle does not follow your advice in Romans chapters one and two.  Nor does Jesus of Nazareth in his many discourses. There is no 'difficulty'. There is sin and there is unblelief. I disagree fundamentally and robustly with your suggestion.

@Mark Paul preached in Acts 17:16-34.. He neither argued nor debated. And one is always ready to give an answer if someone is genuinely moved by the hope one expresses in Christ. But, again, that is neither argument nor debate. You are excusing prolonged argumentation with irrelevant texts. 'The servant of the Lord is not to strive' is more apposite, 2 Timothy 2:24. ('Strive' is also rendered 'quarrelsome' by some.)

@NigelJ You see what is given you to see, and that's good. But of course other people might also be given to see with the eyes of others. Yes there's sin and unbelief. But who's without sin? Are you?

@NigelJ Jesus does more than preaching. Also, seeing with the eyes of others doesn't imply agreeing, but does imply understanding & compassion, which lies behind a everyday expression "I see your point".  In this lecture about co-knowing citing 1 Cor 9:19-23 ("... I have become all things to all people, so that I may be every possible means save some ..."  ) in minute 35, it's implied that St. Paul practiced compassion w/ the blind Jews, but obviously wouldn't sin.

@MikeBorden Ha yes I get your point. But then what is the point of apologetic debate?

I would say 'giving a reason to everyone who asks for the hope that is in you' is apologetic.  Debate scenarios, however, are a different platform.  No one (apparently) is asking the other anything in 'good faith' in such forums and the pressure of having an audience makes true concession to the opposite view very difficult indeed.  There may be some benefit to individuals in the viewing audience but lots of people viewing on both sides are just getting their intellects tickled or looking for 'instant win' sound-bytes, IMO.

@1277154 - This is an important question with vast implications! However the format needs changing. The first two paragraphs present the question well. But the last 5 paragraphs provide the answer...and should be written separately as an answer. It is quite okay for the questioner to give an answer on BH.SE.   Good insights. Peace.

@raygrant Thanks for your comment! I didn't intend the last 5 paragraphs to provide an answer. More like a (very long) introduction to the question. Providing some context and explation. Because I doubt anyone would understand the question without explaining the term deeper convictions?

Apologetics should definitely focus on rational arguments because at its core, it's about showing that faith makes sense logically. If you can present clear, reasoned answers to tough questions, it opens up a real conversation about whether belief is reasonable. It’s about making sure that what you believe holds up when put to the test, and by doing that, you can actually reach people who are questioning or skeptical.
Bringing in personal convictions too much, though, can distract from the objective issues at hand. It risks making the discussion feel more about personal experience or feelings rather than the actual truth claims of the faith, which might not be as persuasive to someone approaching the topic from a purely intellectual standpoint.

Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my question.

Many Faceted Diamond of ApologeticsTo accurately answer this important question we do well to recognize, first, that  Apologetics is a many-faceted endeavor, and is not limited to "rational arguments".

Rational arguments - intellectual exercises
Historical arguments - In fact some scholars avered that the historicity of Jesus forever removed the discussion out of the philosophy department!
Scientific arguments - "Finite universe," "goldilocks universe," "intelligent design," "irreducible complexity," "origin of life," are all evidences that have brought modern scientists to the point of reconsidering their hesitancy to acknowledge God. [See RETURN TO THE GOD HYPOTHESIS, Steven Meyer]
Charismatic arguments - Factual and confirmed supernatural experiences in the name of Jesus.
Ethical arguments - The solution to the dilemma of explaining the existence of a thing called "good." (And other abstract concepts not inherent in chemicals)
Anthropological arguments - Seeking the purpose for man in the universe.
Charitable arguments - the providential, supernatural benevolence of God which leads to repentance.

Epistemology Not all of these arguments appeal to every one equally. It all depends on a person's epistemology, or method of learning. Some people are more visual, some verbal, some experimental, etc.
And it should be kept in mind that people have various starting points, and therefore differing needs, that Apologetics serves to help:  (a) Apologetics removes obstacles to faith (helping atheists); (b) Apologetics confirms the latent faith of others (open minded seekers); (c) Apologetics removes the doubts of wondering believers (doubting theists).
Preliminary Questions But many Christian apologists recognize the import of this posted question presented here: Make sure one starts any discussion by examining the presumptions (biases, prejudices, up-bring, indoctrination) of the inquiring (or adversarial) Atheist. The subject of the sincerely held "convictions" of the atheist must be broached first.

Some atheism advocacy is the result of a "bad experience" in life (a child was killed).
Some atheism is firmly staunched in the mind because of a misunderstanding of the concept of the person and nature of God. ["I don't believe in that  God either" is a good response, often]
Some atheism is just the result of peer pressure in academia (university indoctrination) without any application of critical thinking.
Some atheism is advocated just because of its alleged association with "proven scientific facts."
And most of all, it must acknowledged that some atheists are so, just because of their nature's inbred hatred for religion---and God Himself that would restrict their morals and folkways. [Note: Huxley admitted that he did not want to believe so nothing would stand in his way of venting his lust!]

Convictions Whichever the case, it is legitimate to say that for many, the convictions of the atheist are simply a philosophical atheism of the gaps in an attempt to bridge their presumptive worldview (of autonomy and independence) with the real world around them! There is a chasm that must be confronted and dealt with. Atheism is their "default mechanism". Philosophical faith (non-empirical, by the way) is their answer to this dilemma...an atheistic faith.
But whether dealing with "open minded" atheists (simply led astray by lack of knowledge), or  confronting adamant atheists, it is protocol for any apologists to seek or ask for the underlying convictions behind their belief (convictions). The presumptions of the atheist must be exposed (admitted) before meaningful dialogue can occur.
One apologist of note has advocated the Socratic method of dialogue, which utilizes the asking of question in order for the inquirer to personally discover the reasonings behind his position! [William Lane Craig] The atheist's own answers reveal the tenuous nature of his position (beliefs), when they are taken to their logical conclusion.
A true, effective apologist would indeed consider the deep convictions (preconceived assumptions) of, not just an atheist, but any adversary seeking truth in an honest way.
